# Esp8266-01 Arduino Uno. Status to Firebase

Tags: firebase, arduino, esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I am having problems connecting my Esp8266-01 to my Arduino Uno. I want to be able to connect it so that it can send the below code for a microswitch to Firebase (+LLC). I am not getting any response from AT commands in the serial monitor and have tried both NL & CR as well as changing from 9600 to 115200 baud rate. My esp only displays a red led and not the blue one.

````
int pressSwitch = 0;
void setup()
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
{
pinMode(LEVER_SWITCH_PIN,INPUT);
pressSwitch = digitalRead(LEVER_SWITCH_PIN);
  if(pressSwitch == HIGH)
{
Serial.println("CLOSED");
delay(1000);
}

if(pressSwitch == LOW)
{
Serial.println("OPEN");
delay(1000);
}
}```
````

Comment: Your code does not communicate with ESP-01, in order to do that you need to create a SoftwareSerial connection with the ESP-01. Also how is your Arduino physically connect with the ESP-01? Please noted that Arduino is a 5V MCU, and ESP-01 is a 3V3 MCU, you will need a voltage divider between Arduino Tx and ESP-01 Rx.